# Combine migration in and out data by different common columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two datasets, one for migration inflow to county A from other counties and other for migration outflow from county A to other counties. In order to combine the two data sets as:

Desired output:

```
Key         County          State   FIPS    Inflow  Outflow FiscalYear  Year
510012012   Accomack County VA      51001   NA      27      2011 - 2012 2012
160012012   Ada County      ID      16001   12      18      2011 - 2012 2012
80012012    Adams County    CO      8001    22      39      2011 - 2012 2012
80012011    Adams County    CO      8001    42      31      2010 - 2011 2011
450032012   Aiken County    SC      45003   NA      21      2011 - 2012 2012
120012012   Alachua County  FL      12001   433     NA      2011 - 2012 2012
```

Part of the problem is that the common columns have unequal number of rows. Another problem is that different counties can belong to the same state as shown in the dummy data below. So, what I am thinking is to have a unique key (Key) for both destination and origin county by `concatenating` `FIPS` (unique for each county) and `Year`. That way I can combine the counties with their respective states and the rest of the associated columns values in a single row.

How can I combine the two into one dataset in such a way that I don't have to hardcode each and every common county and state name and FIPS and Year? Missing values would be `NA`.

My original migration outflow data has 517 observations and migration inflow has 441, thus different number of counties in each dataset.

Sample data:

```
    # People moving out of county A to other counties
        inflow_df =  structure(list(Origin_FIPS = c(12001L, 8001L, 16001L, 12001L, 
8001L, 16001L), Origin_StateName = c("FL", "CO", "ID", "FL", 
"CO", "ID"), Origin_Place = c("Alachua County", "Adams County", 
"Ada County", "Alachua County", "Adams County", "Ada County"), 
    InIndividuals = c(433L, 30L, 16L, 381L, 42L, 21L), FiscalYear = c("2011 - 2012", 
    "2011 - 2012", "2011 - 2012", "2010 - 2011", "2010 - 2011", 
    "2010 - 2011"), Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2011L, 
    2011L), Key = c(120012012L, 80012012L, 160012012L, 120012011L, 
    80012011L, 160012011L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
        
  # People moving in county A from other counties
  outflow_df =  structure(list(Dest_FIPS = c(51001L, 16001L, 8001L, 8001L, 45003L
    ), Dest_StateName = c("VA", "ID", "CO", "CO", "SC"), Dest_Place = c("Accomack County", 
    "Ada County", "Adams County", "Adams County", "Aiken County"), 
        OutIndividuals = c(27L, 16L, 39L, 31L, 21L), FiscalYear = c("2011 - 2012", 
        "2011 - 2012", "2011 - 2012", "2010 - 2011", "2011 - 2012"
        ), Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2012L), Key = c(510012012L, 
        160012012L, 80012012L, 80012011L, 450032012L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L))
```

Comment: @akrun, sir, I did try to create an expected desired output, hope it makes sense.

Comment: Here you go sir, Key, for both destination and origin county by `concatenating` `FIPS` (unique for each county) and the `Year` column.

Comment: Sir, `Individuals` represent `inflow` and `outflow` in each `dfs` case

Comment: Your data still have some typos.  I hope the below solution helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
bind_rows(lst(Inflow_df, Outflow_df), .id = 'datname') %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), names_to = ".value",
   names_pattern = ".*_([^_]+$)") %>% 
  mutate(Key = str_c(County, Year), rn = rowid(Key, datname))  %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = datname, values_from = Individuals) %>% 
  arrange(rn) %>% 
  select(-rn)
```

Comment: The code did work sir, however, I am not too confident whether the final data is as intended or not, can I kindly send you the my data and the data output from the code in the chat for your review?

Comment: Sir, I have added sample data from the original data to the question.

Comment: There is one `inflow_df` and `Inflow_df` in your data

Comment: Fixed sir, thank you for pointing it out, the code doesn't add `inflow` and `outflow` in the same row based on the common ` key`.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy because there are multiple issues 1) there are difference in class integer vs character in a column, 2) your input doesn't have the same kind of column names as in the earlier version

Comment: @Ed_Gravy In the new data ,you have only `Origin_StateName` and no `Dest_StateName`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I will get back to the person who sent me the data and get back to you.

Comment: And I think I should also ask them to add `Dest_StateName` to their dataset.

Comment: Hi sir, I received the updated dataset from my colleague and I have sample data from it to the question. Please let me know if you have any questions or you would like me to make some changes to it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy This new format of columns is diffrent.  Perhaps you want `full_join(inflow_df, outflow_df) %>% rename(In_Individuals = InIndividuals, Out_Individuals = OutIndividuals) %>% pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), names_to = ".value",
   names_pattern = ".*_([^_]+$)", values_drop_na = TRUE)`

Comment: Morning sir, the code works except that it's putting both `inflow` and `outflow` values under `Individuals` columns, whereas I would like to have them separate but in the same row, please see the updated `desired output` for further reference, thank you.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy if you have different column patterns, it is better to create a new post

Comment: Alright sir, apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Posted sir, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74279998/combine-migration-in-and-out-data).

Comment: Yes sir, I am thankful for you time and help, sincerely.