# Combine migration in and out data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two datasets, one for migration inflow to county A from other counties and other for migration outflow from county A to other counties. In order to combine the two data sets as:

Desired output:

```
Key         County          State   FIPS    Inflow  Outflow FiscalYear  Year
510012012   Accomack County VA      51001   NA      27      2011 - 2012 2012
160012012   Ada County      ID      16001   16      16      2011 - 2012 2012
80012012    Adams County    CO      8001    39      30      2011 - 2012 2012
80012011    Adams County    CO      8001    42      31      2010 - 2011 2011
450032012   Aiken County    SC      45003   NA      21      2011 - 2012 2012
120012012   Alachua County  FL      12001   433     NA      2011 - 2012 2012
```

How can I combine the two into one dataset in such a way that I don't have to hardcode each and every common county and state name and FIPS and Year? Missing values would be NA.

The common value between the two data sets is the `key`.

My original migration outflow data has 517 observations and migration inflow has 441, thus different number of counties in each dataset.

Sample data:

```
# People moving out of county A to other counties
        inflow_df =  structure(list(Origin_FIPS = c(12001L, 8001L, 16001L, 12001L, 
8001L, 16001L), Origin_StateName = c("FL", "CO", "ID", "FL", 
"CO", "ID"), Origin_Place = c("Alachua County", "Adams County", 
"Ada County", "Alachua County", "Adams County", "Ada County"), 
    InIndividuals = c(433L, 30L, 16L, 381L, 42L, 21L), FiscalYear = c("2011 - 2012", 
    "2011 - 2012", "2011 - 2012", "2011 - 2012", "2010 - 2011", 
    "2010 - 2011"), Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2011L, 
    2011L), Key = c(120012012L, 80012012L, 160012012L, 120012011L, 
    80012011L, 160012011L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
        
# People moving in county A from other counties
  outflow_df =  structure(list(Dest_FIPS = c(51001L, 16001L, 8001L, 8001L, 45003L
    ), Dest_StateName = c("VA", "ID", "CO", "CO", "SC"), Dest_Place = c("Accomack County", 
    "Ada County", "Adams County", "Adams County", "Aiken County"), 
        OutIndividuals = c(27L, 16L, 39L, 31L, 21L), FiscalYear = c("2011 - 2012", 
        "2011 - 2012", "2011 - 2012", "2011 - 2012", "2011 - 2012"
        ), Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2012L), Key = c(510012012L, 
        160012012L, 80012012L, 80012011L, 450032012L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L))
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from your prior question? They seem very similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238885/combine-migration-in-and-out-data-by-different-common-columns

Comment: I would have expected `inflow_df` would mention the county of destination and `outflow_df` would mention the county of origin. Are the table names swapped?

Comment: @JonSpring, I was suggested to create a new post since that post's original sample data was different. Should I delete that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can collate the two tables by giving them consistent names (presumably `Origin_Place` in one should match with `Dest_Place` in the other) and then performing a join. `full_join` outputs all the keys found in either table, in this case `c("Key", "County", "State", "FIPS", "FiscalYear", "Year")`.

I would have expected that the `inflow_df` would reflect the counties that are seeing inflows (ie the destinations) and `outflow_df` would reflect the counties that have outflows (ie the origins), so it seems possible the table names are swapped in the question.

```
inflow2 <- 
  inflow_df %>%
  transmute(Key,
            County = Origin_Place,
            State  = Origin_StateName,
            FIPS   = Origin_FIPS,
            Inflow = InIndividuals,
            FiscalYear,
            Year)

outflow2 <- 
  outflow_df %>%
  transmute(Key,
            County  = Dest_Place,
            State   = Dest_StateName,
            FIPS    = Dest_FIPS,
            Outflow = OutIndividuals,
            FiscalYear,
            Year)

inflow2 %>%
  full_join(outflow2)
```

Result (updated with data from 2022-11-04)

```
Joining, by = c("Key", "County", "State", "FIPS", "FiscalYear", "Year")
        Key          County State  FIPS Inflow  FiscalYear Year Outflow
1 120012012  Alachua County    FL 12001    433 2011 - 2012 2012      NA
2  80012012    Adams County    CO  8001     30 2011 - 2012 2012      39
3 160012012      Ada County    ID 16001     16 2011 - 2012 2012      16
4 120012011  Alachua County    FL 12001    381 2011 - 2012 2011      NA
5  80012011    Adams County    CO  8001     42 2010 - 2011 2011      NA
6 160012011      Ada County    ID 16001     21 2010 - 2011 2011      NA
7 510012012 Accomack County    VA 51001     NA 2011 - 2012 2012      27
8  80012011    Adams County    CO  8001     NA 2011 - 2012 2011      31
9 450032012    Aiken County    SC 45003     NA 2011 - 2012 2012      21
```

Comment: You were right, the sample data was incorrect, as what I wanted was the rows from the two datasets with the same key should be combined into one row in the new df as shown in desired data. However, full join does not do that. I have tried fixing the sample data, hope it's correct now, sorry about that.

Comment: So now in the updated sample data's case, `Ada` and `Adams` county in and out data for fiscal year  `2012` should be in one row in the new dataset based on the common key.

Comment: Is it working as you want?

Comment: No in my data's case it's still putting the rows with the common key as two separate rows (one row each for in and out data respectively for the same county and year) instead of one row in the output df.

Comment: Actually it's working for some common keys but not all of them.

Comment: If it's not much can I send you the migration in and out `CSVs` in chat?

Comment: I think I know the problem now, the rows that are not fully joining are for the fiscal year 2013, and that's because the in migration in data Fiscal year is `2012 -2013` and for migration out data it's `2012 - 2013`. Thus this fiscal year  does not match up in the two dfs and ends up being two rows in the output df

Comment: For some reason, that I can still can't figure out it is that some counties' rows are duplicated with the exact same information.

Comment: Data cleaning can be tricky, especially if there are hand-typed values like "2012 -2013" or even more pernicious ones like "2012 - 2013 ". You might review your data using functions like `distinct` and `count`, and sort your data to catch near-misses. If some rows are literally identical, you could use `distinct` to de-dupe them.

Comment: Thank you, yes I ended up removing dupes via `unique()`.